# Alternate of SingletonItem in Saxon-9.7-HE

Tags: java, xslt-2.0, saxon

In our project they were using saxon-9.5. Now I have update saxon-9.5 to saxon-9.7. In previous version we were using **net.sf.saxon.value.SingletonItem** class. After updating with saxon-9.7-HE, I am getting error for this class.

Question:- Have net.sf.saxon.value.SingletonItem changed with other class in saxon-9.7? Any help

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: net.sf.saxon.value.SingletonItem class is not available in Saxon-9.7-HE, is there any alternate for this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SingletonItem` in 9.5 was a wrapper class used to wrap a `NodeInfo` so that it implemented the interface `net.sf.saxon.om.Item`. It is no longer needed in Saxon 9.7 because `NodeInfo` now implements `net.sf.saxon.om.Item` directly.